# How to hide times icon on closed side slide navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I'm customizing a Shopify template and I have created color picker from scratch. Now I have created a X button which closes sliding side navigation, and I wanted to place the X button outside the sidenav but when the side navigation is closed the button is still there. I have tried adding a lower z-index to it, and adding a higher z-index to header, and it didnt worked. I will be much thankful for the help.

**Open Side Nav:**

[image]

**Closed Side Nav:**

[image]

As you can see the X button stays after sidenav is closed.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="sidetimes">

<i class="fas fa-times" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>

</div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.sidetimes {
padding: 11px 30px 11px 10px;
background: #07c;
display: inline-block;
width: 27px;
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
color: #fff;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: -10px 5px 14px 0px #444;
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 5px 14px 0px #444;
-webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
transform: translateX(0) translateZ(0);
-webkit-animation: sliding-panel-close-button-in .4s forwards;
animation: sliding-panel-close-button-in .4s forwards;
-webkit-animation-delay: .3s;
animation-delay: .3s;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9999;
top: 36px;
margin-left: 39.5px;
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to find this sidepanel in screenshot product page [link](https://www.peppigel.com/collections/our-best-sellers/products/nail-dipping-powder-starter-kit) where i find working example of your sidepanel ? Thanks

Comment: This theme is on preview thats because it isnt showing it to you. Im working on a new theme and I this is just a preview. If you are intested I can give you credentials so you can log in and see the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your are using Javascript to control this animation? If so, the solution is to toggle a class on the `body` when the menu is "open"

See the example

```js
$(".open-icon, .close-icon").click(function(e){
  $("body").toggleClass("menu-open");
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 5px;
}

body.menu-open nav {
  left: 0;
}

body.menu-open .open-icon {
  display: none;
}

body.menu-open .close-icon {
  display: block;
}

.close-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -30px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.open-icon {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="open-icon">MENU</span>
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrap">
    <p class="close-icon">&times;</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 8</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I already did it myself and I did it this way. But thanks for helping!

Comment: I have no Regrets for helping you ;)